# how to make type of return value to be lower case keyof typeof enum

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
enum Fruit {
  'Apple',
  'Banana',
  'Peach'
}

function foo(str:keyof typeof Fruit){
  return str.replace(/^[A-Z]{1}/, (d:string) => d.toLocaleLowerCase());
}

const res = foo('Apple');
```

I'd like to make type of return value of foo to be 'apple' | 'banana' | 'peach'.

How can I reach that? (Don't define return value as 'apple' | 'banana' | 'peach' manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`LowerCase`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#lowercasestringtype) to get the lower case union of strings as the return type. If you only want the first character to be lower case, use [`Uncapitalize`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uncapitalizestringtype).

```
function foo(str: keyof typeof Fruit) {
  return str.replace(
    /^[A-Z]{1}/, (d:string) => d.toLocaleLowerCase()
  ) as Lowercase<keyof typeof Fruit>
}

const res = foo('Apple');
//    ^? const res: "apple" | "banana" | "peach"
```

But you might as well just return the correct constituent of the union by making `str` generic.

```
function foo<T extends keyof typeof Fruit>(str: T) {
  return str.replace(
    /^[A-Z]{1}/, (d:string) => d.toLocaleLowerCase()
  ) as Lowercase<T>
}
const res = foo('Apple');
//    ^? const res: "apple"
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFygbwFBSgcgIIAOBANsDgDRa4BCAhiPbRVTgArC0DGAFjhgL4YMmbADMwITskQB7EFFEyZACgDOyOAC4oAa2ABPGaKjJ9BYEdgIUASnRVscYMjBx56uADonJLsGUO2FAA9AB6ANp4ALQAWgC6aACM-MHkUMoAJpoeiCAA5nYAvAB8UBmeyDIAMjKctKQ1AO7AcADCtKr+NoF2HVBNLXWdADx6hsam5pbwSMjFVIJUnHLqUE6qUIUKSsr4RKQ4NgDcVMHBQVChAPxQyyCr69oARLT7wE9QAD5QTwBGjAwPt8nuYuNwngIhCIFBIpLJ5IoZMMACpQYAAD2QoAyGzGlkmFmMMxQxTUGm0yLs0Mczlc7g03mAvk4-kC2DCkViCWSqXSWRy+SKpXKlRqdQaMmabQ6XR6UD6AzgQ2AKPm2EW2DuD2AGy2iN2hBIZGOp3OQWutxWqEeP1eRoh-CAA)